# A word or idiom for a religion which gets blamed for a single person's misguided activity

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests

The title is self-explanatory. Thanks for any help you are being able to provide.

Comment: To be frank, I do not find the title so self-explanatory. I am struggling to find an actual example, and I wonder why this would only apply to a religion. I think the phenomenon is more common in smaller groups, like a family (the whole family gets blamed for the misbehaviour of one of the members). That would be called **guilt by association**. Why you would be looking for a specifically religious version or why you expect there to be a _single_ word for that, escapes me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not even going to try to think of a single word, but I believe the most fitting idiom would be [**guilt by association**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_fallacy).

It is a logical fallacy that is used to imply that someone is guilty fro sharing certain properties with someone we *do* consider guilty.

It is not exclusively applied to religions, and I see no reason why religions would need a special expression for this all-too-common fallacy.

For a religion, the "logic" may go as follows:

> Osama bin Laden (says he) is a Muslim.
>   Osama bin Laden is a terrorist.
>   Conclusion -> muslims are terrorists.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you may be seeking a term like [*scapegoat:*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/scapegoat?s=t)

> a person made to bear the blame for others

To answer your specific question, one may thus speak of a *scapegoat religion* or of *a religion being scapegoated*.

Comment: Would that not be the _opposite_ of what is asked? A scapegoat being blamed for everything a religion does wrong? I have never heard scapegoat being used to blame a _group_ for the actions of an _individual_...

Comment: @oerkelens - To illustrate my point, consider how the Islamic religion is held blameworthy by many for the actions of certain terrorists or marauders who claim (falsely) to be promoting that religion or its values through their actions. In this situation, the religion is being scapegoated for the activities of the terrorists.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be referring to the superficiality with which people tend to to give opinions without having real and deep knowledge of facts or events: the following idiom, though not specific to religion, conveys the concept:

[Don't judge a book by its cover](http://web.mit.edu/21h.418/www/jrozier/adage7.html):

> - something that you say which means you cannot judge the quality or character of someone or something just by looking at them
> - We live in a very superficial society. It is very easy to fall into the trap of looking only at the surface of people, things, and ideas without taking the time and effort to delve deeper into them. This is where the adage "Don't Judge a Book By Its Cover" comes from. Literally, you cannot tell the quality of the contents of a book just by looking at the material used to hold it together. A book with a plain cover and simple title may be more important, more entertaining, or more useful than a book bound in a flashier manner.

Source: http://web.mit.edu/21h.418/www/jrozier/adage7.html

Answer (score 0):

I just up-voted the answer from oerkelens (guilt by association), which would match your question closely.

However, in case you are looking for a single word for the practice of (or tendency to) make accusations without regard to sufficient evidence on a case-by-case basis, McCarthyism has been a popular term since the 1950s.  The word originally referred to the practice of subjecting to repression anyone who held views that even remotely leaned towards communism.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McCarthyism.